# when showing large amount of data graph not displaying from middle

Tags: chart.js

Using Chartjs-v2.9.3, the line or bar from the middle to the end of the graph is not displaying. But the tooltip is showing data.

However, when using same data in Chartjs-v2.4.0, all the data lines are displayed in the graph.

Here is  Chartjs-v2.9.3 result:
[image]

But with Chartjs-v2.4.0, there is no display problem.

Here is the data used for both.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer');
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    "labels": ["03/01 00:00", "03/01 01:00", "03/01 02:00", "03/01 03:00", "03/01 04:00", "03/01 05:00", ...x500],
    "datasets": [{
      "pointRadius": 0,
      "pointBorderWidth": 0,
      "pointStyle": "rectRounded",
      "lineTension": 0,
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "fill": false,
      "borderColor": "blue",
      "backgroundColor": "blue",
      "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...x500]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio:false,
    responsive:true,
    legend:{
      display:false,position:"top",align:"start"},
    scales:{
      yAxes:[
        {ticks:{min:0,beginAtZero:true}}],
      xAxes:[
        {ticks:{minRotation:0,maxRotation:80}}]},
      tooltips:{intersect:false,position:"nearest",callbacks:{}}
    }
})
```

and just a simple display in Html:

```
<body>
  <div style="overflow:auto;position:relative;width:33480px;height:500px;" >
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wwwfernand/c5ran1b6/1/)

Is there a display limit in Chartjs?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your html `div` style.

Don't know what you want to achieve with these numbers, but without them everything is fine.

https://jsbin.com/gogufonibi/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<div>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="3480px" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: We have to show a large span of data, so it needs to be scrollable.